# Converting a StreamReader to a Stream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

The Deserialize method in protobuff-net takes in a Stream as a argument. Before I used to use FileStream and pass that and it worked , but now I have to use StreamReader cause I'm porting the app for windows store/phone. and I'm getting the following error :

```
 error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.StreamReader' to 'System.IO.Stream'
```

Also this is a unity3d project and the other error I'm getting is :

```
error CS4028: 'await' requires that the type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.StorageFolder>' have a suitable GetAwaiter method. Are you missing a using directive for 'System'?
```

This is weird because I have wrapped the code in `#if NETFX_CORE #endif`
Here are the includes I'm using:

```
#if NETFX_CORE

using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
#endif
```

Comment: StreamReader is not inherited from Stream class so nothing strange about this error

Comment: Please only ask about *one* question per post. These appear to be unrelated errors (or at least, you haven't shown any relationship between them).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't, logically - a `StreamReader` is for *text* data, whereas protobuf data is *binary* data. It's not clear where you're getting the `StreamReader` from, but you should look for APIs designed for binary data instead.

In practice, you *may* be able to use [`StreamReader.BaseStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.basestream.aspx) to get at the underlying stream, but you shouldn't be creating a `StreamReader` to read from non-text data anyway... and constructing the reader may try to read text data from the stream and complain if it doesn't find it...

Comment: @UriPopov: Well a very quick search found [`OpenStreamForReadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582102(v=vs.110).aspx), if that helps you...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you possibly look at the second error. Sorry if i'm being dumb but this is my first time developing for windows phone and I have a feeling that unity3d does not handle this platform well.

Comment: @UriPopov: Please ask the second error as a separate post. You should also specify which version of Windows Phone you're targeting, and which version of Unity you're using.